# regular expression to find words that are not links in FrontPage

Tags: regex, frontpage

FrontPage 2003 has an option to Find with regular expressions, and I need to look for words that are not links..

For example, to find the word "Download" or "any text download something" that doesn't have the "a" tag before and after

I mean something that doesn't have the tags

```
<a href>  </a>
```

before and after

Comment: <a> isn't a link, it's an anchor. It only becomes a link after it has an href attribute (actually other ways too, which you couldn't possibly detect in a single regexp on one file).

Comment: So if you had a single link with 100 words in it, then you wouldn't want to match any of those words either? I don't think regexp is the right tool for the job. This is exactly what XPath is for.

Comment: yes, I meant a href, sorry.  re matching the word that is inside any link, I just wanna find that word..  and links normally are 1-3 words or something..  not that many words..

Comment: Combining a positive (for example "download") with a negative (for example "not <a" in a single regular expression is at best tricky and often just plain impossible. I'd recommend a _two stage_ process (stage I find all "download"; then stage II eliminate all "<a") - easy from the command line, but I don't know how to do it in FrontPage.